# Passing repository variable to GitHub action in organization

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repository environment variable [
`METRICS_PUBLIC_KEY`.

[image]

I have [a GitHub action](https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/example/blob/move/.github/workflows/pull_request.yml) which sets this as an environment variable:

```
    - name: CI Metrics
      # To be more stable you can use a tag e.g.
      # https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ci-metrics/script/v0.1.0/run.py
      run: |
        wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ci-metrics/script/master/run.py
        python3 ./run.py
      env:
        # Variables to interact with CI Metrics.
        PUBLIC_KEY: ${{ vars.METRICS_PUBLIC_KEY }}
        PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.METRICS_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        # Variables to upload
        HEAD: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
        DATA_FILE: "./metrics"
        # Variables to diff
        TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        BASE: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}
        ISSUE: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
```

The script prints all the environment variables [here](https://github.com/ci-metrics/script/blob/master/run.py#L147) which gives:

```
os.environ: environ({'SELENIUM_JAR_PATH': '/usr/share/java/selenium-server.jar', 'CONDA': '/usr/share/miniconda', 'GITHUB_WORKSPACE': '/home/runner/work/example/example', 'JAVA_HOME_11_X64': '/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-11-jdk-amd64', 'GITHUB_PATH': '/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/add_path_719d570f-76bc-4425-94fa-0f578678f68f', 'GITHUB_ACTION': '__run_2', 'JAVA_HOME': '/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-11-jdk-amd64', 'GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER': '4', 'RUNNER_NAME': 'GitHub Actions 1', 'GRADLE_HOME': '/usr/share/gradle-8.4', 'GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID': '150619653', 'ACTIONS_RUNNER_ACTION_ARCHIVE_CACHE': '/opt/actionarchivecache', 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME': '/home/runner/.config', 'DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE': '1', 'ANT_HOME': '/usr/share/ant', 'JAVA_HOME_8_X64': '/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-8-jdk-amd64', 'GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR': 'JonathanWoollett-Light', 'GITHUB_REF_TYPE': 'branch', 'HOMEBREW_CLEANUP_PERIODIC_FULL_DAYS': '3650', 'ANDROID_NDK': '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653', 'BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NONINTERACTIVE': '1', 'PWD': '/home/runner/work/example/example', 'PIPX_BIN_DIR': '/opt/pipx_bin', 'STATS_TRP': 'true', 'STATS_BLT': 'true', 'GOROOT_1_20_X64': '/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.20.10/x64', 'GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID': '717843427', 'DEPLOYMENT_BASEPATH': '/opt/runner', 'GITHUB_ACTIONS': 'true', 'STATS_VMD': 'true', 'ANDROID_NDK_LATEST_HOME': '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125', 'SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID': '598', 'GITHUB_SHA': 'd3c9496928ecca26aeca8bc99fc1c4403b787e75', 'GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF': 'ci-metrics/example/.github/workflows/pull_request.yml@refs/pull/1/merge', 'POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL': 'GitHub-Actions-ubuntu22', 'RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT': 'github-hosted', 'STATS_EXTP': 'https://provjobdsettingscdn.blob.core.windows.net/settings/provjobdsettings-0.5.154/provjobd.data', 'BASE': '4bf5de3ba2fcdea180e858190ef4fc617c39326e', 'DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP': '0', 'STATS_TIS': 'mining', 'GITHUB_REF': 'refs/pull/1/merge', 'RUNNER_OS': 'Linux', 'GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED': 'false', 'HOME': '/home/runner', 'GITHUB_API_URL': 'https://api.github.com', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'RUNNER_TRACKING_ID': 'github_bb7cf7f6-7df4-4fe6-a546-0a6ff0fa8527', 'RUNNER_ARCH': 'X64', 'GOROOT_1_21_X64': '/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.21.3/x64', 'RUNNER_TEMP': '/home/runner/work/_temp', 'HEAD': 'b7b63d0bc62f125d2426d0687e6eedbcf4aa059b', 'GITHUB_STATE': '/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/save_state_719d570f-76bc-4425-94fa-0f578678f68f', 'EDGEWEBDRIVER': '/usr/local/share/edge_driver', 'JAVA_HOME_21_X64': '/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-21-jdk-amd64', 'GITHUB_ENV': '/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/set_env_719d570f-76bc-4425-94fa-0f578678f68f', 'GITHUB_EVENT_PATH': '/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow/event.json', 'INVOCATION_ID': 'd57a53f7f94844f6890d1811e3e82d05', 'GITHUB_EVENT_NAME': 'pull_request', 'GITHUB_RUN_ID': '6842761175', 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64': '/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64', 'ANDROID_NDK_HOME': '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653', 'GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY': '/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/step_summary_719d570f-76bc-4425-94fa-0f578678f68f', 'HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE': '1', 'GITHUB_ACTOR': 'JonathanWoollett-Light', 'NVM_DIR': '/home/runner/.nvm', 'SGX_AESM_ADDR': '1', 'GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT': '2', 'STATS_RDCL': 'true', 'TOKEN': '***', 'ANDROID_HOME': '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk', 'GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL': 'https://api.github.com/graphql', 'RUNNER_USER': 'runner', 'ACCEPT_EULA': 'Y', 'PRIVATE_KEY': '', 'STATS_UE': 'true', 'USER': 'runner', 'ISSUE': '1', 'GITHUB_SERVER_URL': 'https://github.com', 'STATS_V3PS': 'true', 'PIPX_HOME': '/opt/pipx', 'CARGO_TERM_COLOR': 'always', 'GECKOWEBDRIVER': '/usr/local/share/gecko_driver', 'STATS_EXT': 'true', 'CHROMEWEBDRIVER': '/usr/local/share/chromedriver-linux64', 'SHLVL': '1', 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT': '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk', 'VCPKG_INSTALLATION_ROOT': '/usr/local/share/vcpkg', 'GITHUB_ACTOR_ID': '16856679', 'RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE': '/opt/hostedtoolcache', 'ImageVersion': '20231030.2.0', 'DOTNET_NOLOGO': '1', 'GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA': 'd3c9496928ecca26aeca8bc99fc1c4403b787e75', 'GITHUB_REF_NAME': '1/merge', 'GITHUB_JOB': 'rust', 'DATA_FILE': './metrics', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1001', 'AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR': '/opt/az/azcliextensions', 'PERFLOG_LOCATION_SETTING': 'RUNNER_PERFLOG', 'GITHUB_REPOSITORY': 'ci-metrics/example', 'ANDROID_NDK_ROOT': '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653', 'CHROME_BIN': '/usr/bin/google-chrome', 'GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS': '90', 'JOURNAL_STREAM': '8:19626', 'RUNNER_WORKSPACE': '/home/runner/work/example', 'LEIN_HOME': '/usr/local/lib/lein', 'LEIN_JAR': '/usr/local/lib/lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.10.0-standalone.jar', 'GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY': '', 'PATH': '/home/runner/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/runner/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'RUNNER_PERFLOG': '/home/runner/perflog', 'GITHUB_BASE_REF': 'master', 'GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX': '/usr/local', 'CI': 'true', 'SWIFT_PATH': '/usr/share/swift/usr/bin', 'ImageOS': 'ubuntu22', 'GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER': 'ci-metrics', 'GITHUB_HEAD_REF': 'move', 'GITHUB_ACTION_REF': '', 'PUBLIC_KEY': '', 'GOROOT_1_19_X64': '/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.19.13/x64', 'GITHUB_WORKFLOW': '.github/workflows/pull_request.yml', 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND': 'noninteractive', 'GITHUB_OUTPUT': '/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/set_output_719d570f-76bc-4425-94fa-0f578678f68f', 'AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY': '/opt/hostedtoolcache', '_': '/usr/bin/python3'})
```

See https://github.com/ci-metrics/example/actions/runs/6842761175/job/18604627115?pr=1

Here we see `, 'PUBLIC_KEY': '',` and `, 'PRIVATE_KEY': '',` which are both incorrect. `PUBLIC_KEY` should be `, 'PUBLIC_KEY': '6546b543a35b7d5af8c93a7b'`.

Notably we also see `, 'DATA_FILE': './metrics',` and `, 'TOKEN': '***',` so these are correctly set.

What am I missing here? Why is it reading the repository variables as empty?

Comment: Environment variables using `var` are set in a repository [environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment), those are set at the job level, as stated [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment). What environment did you set at the job level in your workflow? This part doesn't appear in your question, and if not set, this could explain what the variable isn't filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the organisation settings under the `Fork pull request workflows in private repositories` header you can configure how actions from forks are run and if secrets are shared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like repository variables are not available to workflows that are triggered by a pull request from a fork. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/44322).

In your case, your workflow is running in the context of the fork, which means you must define those variables in that fork for the run to succeed.

I can't find the exact place where the author of the discussion was quoting from. However, it's worth mentioning that repo vars are still a beta feature and thus are subject to change.